# Possible non-linearity pspline Cox model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, splines, nonlinear

Our working group ran a Cox regression with a p-spline to model the possible non-linearity of continuous variables. However, I'm a bit confused with the interpretation of the linearity or non-linearity of a term.

Here's our model:

```r
CoxModel_spline < -coxph(Surv(as.numeric(time), status) ~ 
      rurality + pspline(age_diag) + unemployment + 
      pspline(as.numeric(delay)), data)

summary(CoxModel_spline)

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(as.numeric(time), status) ~ rurality + 
     pspline(age_diag) + unemployment + 
     pspline(as.numeric(delay)), data)

n= 9417, number of events= 298 
   (3042 observations deleted due to missingness)

                          coef       se(coef)  se2       Chisq DF   p      
ruralityUrban              0.6064811 0.2748575 0.2748049  4.87 1.00 2.7e-02
pspline(age_diag), linear -0.0168872 0.0044320 0.0044315 14.52 1.00 1.4e-04
pspline(age_diag), nonlin                                 5.10 3.02 1.7e-01
unemploymentYes            0.5068094 0.1338692 0.1338014 14.33 1.00 1.5e-04
pspline(as.numeric(delay) -0.0008533 0.0009525 0.0009506  0.80 1.00 3.7e-01
pspline(as.numeric(delay)                                 6.88 3.05 7.8e-02

                          exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
ruralityUrban                1.8340     0.5453   1.07012    3.1430
ps(age_diag)3                1.4268     0.7009   0.31525    6.4576
ps(age_diag)4                2.0032     0.4992   0.17119   23.4400
ps(age_diag)5                2.5607     0.3905   0.14375   45.6137
ps(age_diag)6                2.2530     0.4438   0.12276   41.3506
ps(age_diag)7                1.4608     0.6846   0.08268   25.8088
ps(age_diag)8                1.2719     0.7863   0.07201   22.4632
ps(age_diag)9                1.1092     0.9015   0.06213   19.8051
ps(age_diag)10               0.8862     1.1284   0.04899   16.0332
ps(age_diag)11               1.0100     0.9901   0.05490   18.5828
ps(age_diag)12               1.4339     0.6974   0.06977   29.4702
ps(age_diag)13               2.0989     0.4764   0.06566   67.1006
ps(age_diag)14               3.0672     0.3260   0.03830  245.5962
unemploymentYes              1.6600     0.6024   1.27689    2.1580
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.5518     1.8122   0.21416    1.4218
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3398     2.9425   0.09914    1.1649
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.2985     3.3505   0.09123    0.9764
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3013     3.3189   0.09381    0.9678
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3209     3.1162   0.09760    1.0551
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3396     2.9446   0.10077    1.1445
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3357     2.9786   0.09680    1.1643
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3795     2.6349   0.10499    1.3719
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.4296     2.3279   0.11172    1.6518
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.4153     2.4081   0.09227    1.8689
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3537     2.8274   0.04865    2.5713
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.2988     3.3468   0.01644    5.4298
```

From my understanding, `age_diag` is linear, as the non-linear term is non-significant and none of the different coefficients is significant. However, I'm a bit confused with the interpretation of the variable `delay` as it seems that it's not linear but also not non-linear, considering the significance level of 0.05. However, it does seem odd the variable being nothing. Can we consider the variable non-linear? I'm also inclined to consider the variable non-linear as some coefficients are significant

```r
(**ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.2985     3.3505   0.09123    0.9764     
ps(as.numeric(delay))        0.3013     3.3189   0.09381    0.9678**).
```

What does this mean? I've seen a few questions and read the vignette but it would be helpful to confirm the rationale. The `termplot` is below and it also seems a bit tricky to understand.

[image]

Let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Evidence for nonlinearity is based on the composite "chunk" test for all nonlinear terms combined, which is provided for you in the output.  **But** as detailed in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms), nonlinearity is something that you almost always expect to be there, and the classic Grambsch and O'Brien paper discussed in the RMS course notes shows by simulation that statistical inference is distorted if you remove nonlinear terms just because of small estimated effects or large p-values.  So assessment of nonlinearity is something we do (1) for descriptive purposes, (2) to impress your boss by bringing evidence that things are not trivial, and (3) for future planning.

psplines are not as readily explained or used as simple basis splines like the restricted cubic spline I use in RMS.  With restricted cubic splines you get a relatively simple equation, and in the R `rms` package the `latex` and `Function` functions can be used to obtain that equation.  These simple splines have integer degrees of freedom and fit just as well but you have to pre-specify the number of knots.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! Just to give a bit more background info. `delay` is the time from symptoms until diagnosis, so I don't expect this variable to have linear behaviour, but I got confused with the output. We used the `pspline` especially to avoid specifying the location of the knots, but maybe it's best to use a cubic spline and define knots at the percentiles, or maybe at the beginning? Two, three months of delay is quite large theoretically though the median is a bit higher.

Comment: psplines work well so don't switch just for that reason.